# Ionic 2 StatusBar Color Text

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, statusbar, ionic-view

my problem is: is there a trick for change the StatusBar text color in Ionic 2 or 3? I have installed "cordova-plugin-statusbar" , I can change the background color but is not possible to change the text color.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

```
color: black
```

In HTML if we need to change text color you need to right color property not background property.

Comment: sorry, bat the Ionic plugin has not an html or css file; I tried with backgroundColorByHexString(hexString) for change the background and it works

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the plugin [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar). It have three function to change text color with background. I hope this may help.

```
StatusBar.styleLightContent(); //Light
StatusBar.styleBlackTranslucent(); //Black, translucent
StatusBar.styleBlackOpaque(); //Black, opaque
```

Comment: Yes, it changes background but not the text's colour